# Feature Store Vertex AI for Online Predictions

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-ml, google-cloud-vertex-ai

It is necessary to mantain an online attribute on a Feature Store of Vertex AI to serve an endpoint model to provide real-time predictions??

Comment: Hi @gabriel11, can you clarify your requirement?

Comment: Hi @ShipraSarkar, I have a model in an endpoint. This model serves for an app to make predictions for the users. But the charges for this service (Vertex AI) are so high. When I view the billing by SKU, the most expensive SKU correspond to: Feature Store online serving node (74D1-6081-582A). So my question is, If I the delete the features in Feature Store, Can I lower the billing without damaging the operation of the model?

Comment: Hi @gabriel11, Price of the Vertex AI featurestore depends upon the amount of feature data stored in online and offline storage as mentioned in this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/pricing#featurestore).You can check the feature usage so that it would be easy for you to understand whether it has any impact on the model or not .If your feature data does not have any impact on the model then it can be deleted using the steps mentioned in this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/featurestore/managing-features#delete_a_feature). Let me know if that helps.